# limit PHP script to one domain per license

Tags: php

I'm encoding my script with Ioncube and want to ensure that it works only on the licensed domain. How is this commonly done?

I was thinking something like:

```
function domain(){

}

if($this_domain <> domain()){
   exit('no');
}
```

or

```
$allowed_hosts = array('foo.example.com', 'bar.example.com');
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) || !in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $allowed_hosts)) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 400 Bad Request');
    exit;
}
```

But I'm not sure if that's correct. Would [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) be better?

Comment: You do know it's pretty easily possible to bypass obfuscation schemes for interpreted languages like PHP, right? Since you're trusting your customers anyhow, why not just trust them a little bit more and not put in the restriction? Besides, what does it mean to work "on a domain"? A domain is just a name...

Comment: in the arabic world, every thing differ

Comment: Ioncube PRO have bulit-in mechanism to generate lcence limited to IP/domain

Answer (score 2):

This is a **wasted attempt**. As any determined developer can hack your code and remove the blocking algorithm.

However, as per the algorithm goes, this is fine

```
$allowed_hosts = array('foo.example.com', 'bar.example.com');
if (!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $allowed_hosts)) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 400 Bad Request');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: He mean `encode` instead of `decode`. Lookup what `Ioncube` is and you will know that it is not wasted attempt.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, I dont know whats your problem whether you didn't understand me or just passing away comment that mean nothing. My point in answer is, I could say `Give me the source code of ioncube, I will remove the verification, within less than a day`, because it can be removed. UNDERSTOOD?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, I have coded many obfuscator, encoders, decoder myself, and I know its not the solution of the problem. This sort of stuff you cannot rely on. I hope i made by point clear. Have a NICE day!!!

Comment: No need to shout dude :/. You can say what you want but no one will give you code of ioncube, and that's the whole point - prevent access to the source.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, May be i am talking to a wall. Ok, I will try again. Read their tagline `The ionCube PHP Encoder makes it easy to protect your PHP 4 & 5 source code from easy observation, theft and change`. Did you notice the **`easy observation...`** part, that's my point. It may not easy but still possible.

Comment: And where have I mentioned that it is impossible? I just don't think of it as `wasted attempt` because 99,99% customers who would like to remove this limitation will fail or try searching for a hacker who would charge them 10 times more as additional license...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I have to say that I suggest you to use IonCube "dynamic key" for licensing.

Except this, the new version of this software also has the new ability to build the license directly for each domain. I use it several years but I generate automatic licensing system that uses "dynamic key"

Comment: Dynamic Keys is really to allow code to be protected with strong encryption and without having the encryption key stored anywhere to be discovered by reverse engineering. Licensing related data could be factored into a custom Dynamic Key generation algorithm though. Licensing itself is best checked with Pro/Cerberus native features as the Loader acquires and validates request data before it could be modified by e.g. a PHP prepend script, which by modifying S_SERVER would be one way to attack a home-brew PHP based licensing scheme.